# Rack and rack.request.form_vars / rack.request.form_hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I am doing some middleware that changes the authenticity_token param before it gets to Rails.

I can see that env.inspect gives both rack.request.form_vars and rack.request.form_hash. Both contains the authenticity token. Which one does Rails use and why does Rack provide both?

Comment: I'd like to know this too. Let me know if you find anything out.

Comment: Searching through the rails source tree for `form_vars` and `form_hash` provides no results, suggesting Rails doesn't use either one? I'm as confused as you.

Answer (score 8):

Let's look at the source! The both variables come from using the [`Rack::Request`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb) helper class. It provides a nice interface to the request parameters. It's not necessary for Rack applications to use it, but Rails does use it.

The variables are for `Rack::Request`'s internal use. `rack.request.form_vars` contains the unparsed POST body and `rack.request.form_hash` contains the parsed hash. `ActionDispatch::Request` inherits from `Rack::Request` and it gets the parameters using `Rack::Request#POST`, which reads the latter variable. You could use `Rack::Request` yourself to modify it.

```
class YourMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end 

  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    req.POST["authenticity_token"] = "foo"
  end
end
```

Comment: Looking at the source and understanding the source are two different things :) so thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a recent copy of rack that includes [this pull request](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/381), you can use `Rack::Request#update_param`:

```
request = Rack::Request.new(env)
request.update_param :auth_token, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Just like the `req.POST` solution above, this will persist in the `env` that is passed among middlewares - but it's a higher-level call meant to deal with situations like yours.